# find -regex not recognizing \d digit

Tags: linux, regex, find

I have a directory structure that looks like the following:

```
processor0/10
processor0/10.1
processor0/10.2
processor1/10
processor1/10.1
processor1/10.2
 ...etc...
processor7/10
processor7/10.1
processor7/10.2
```

I'd like to "find" all the directories that are 10.1 or 10.2.

The following works:

```
$ find . -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./processor[0-9]*/10\.(1|2)'
```

but this doesn't:

```
$ find . -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./processor\d*/10\.(1|2)'
```

I'm not sure why, since egrep should understand that \d is a digit.
Can anyone explain this?

This is command-line find on 64-bit Ubuntu - specifically (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

Regards,
Madeleine

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185457/why-doesnt-this-pattern-work-in-egrep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `\d` denotes a decimal digit character in Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which is not supported by `find`.

You could make use of the character classe `[:digit:]`:

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./processor[[:digit:]]*/10\.(1|2)'
```

You may also want to refer to [regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).

Comment: Thanks. I see that. It's hard to keep all the flavors of regex straight. Wish they'd standardize...